# Error in BlockSci compilation

Tags: c++

I was writing a c++ file by calling getTaintedImpl function and I got the below error during its compilation. Could you please be kind enough to help me? Thanks in advance.

The below includes the error, the file which I sed to call the getTaintedImpl (helloworld.cpp) and the CMakefile.txt

```
Error

/root/BlockSci/tools/test/helloworld.cpp: In function 'int main(int, char**)':
/root/BlockSci/tools/test/helloworld.cpp:53:25: error: 'getTaintedImpl' is not a member of 'blocksci::heuristics'
   blocksci::heuristics::getTaintedImpl(func,output,val);
                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
tools/test/CMakeFiles/hello.dir/build.make:62: recipe for target 'tools/test/CMakeFiles/hello.dir/helloworld.cpp.o' failed
make[2]: *** [tools/test/CMakeFiles/hello.dir/helloworld.cpp.o] Error 1
CMakeFiles/Makefile2:730: recipe for target 'tools/test/CMakeFiles/hello.dir/all' failed
make[1]: *** [tools/test/CMakeFiles/hello.dir/all] Error 2
Makefile:151: recipe for target 'all' failed
```

helloworld.cpp

```
#include <blocksci/chain/blockchain.hpp>
#include <blocksci/cluster/cluster_manager.hpp>
#include <blocksci/heuristics/change_address.hpp>
#define taint_hpp
#include <blocksci/heuristics/taint.hpp>
#include <blocksci/address/address.hpp>
#include <blocksci/chain/algorithms.hpp>
#include <blocksci/blocksci_export.h>
#include <blocksci/chain/chain_fwd.hpp>

#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <clipp.h>

#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    std::string dataLocation;
    std::string outputLocation;
    std::string output;
    std::string val;
    std::string func;
    bool overwrite;
    auto cli = (
                clipp::value("data location", dataLocation),
                clipp::value("output location", outputLocation),
                clipp::option("--overwrite").set(overwrite).doc("Overwrite existing cluster files if they exist")
    );
    auto res = parse(argc, argv, cli);
    if (res.any_error()) {
        std::cout << "Invalid command line parameter\n" << clipp::make_man_page(cli, argv[0]);
        return 0;
    }

    blocksci::Blockchain chain(dataLocation);

    //blocksci::ClusterManager::createClustering(chain, blocksci::heuristics::LegacyChange{}, outputLocation, overwrite);
  blocksci::heuristics::getTaintedImpl(func,output,val);
return 0;
}
```

CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(hello)

add_executable(hello helloworld.cpp)

target_compile_options(hello PRIVATE -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic)

if(CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "AppleClang" OR CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_ID STREQUAL "Clang")
target_compile_options(blocksci_clusterer PRIVATE -Weverything -Wno-c++98-compat -Wno-c++98-compat-pedantic -Wno-old-style-cast -Wno-documentation-unknown-command -Wno-documentation -Wno-shadow -Wno-covered-switch-default -Wno-missing-prototypes -Wno-weak-vtables -Wno-unused-macros -Wno-padded)
endif()

target_link_libraries( hello dset)
target_link_libraries( hello clipp)
target_link_libraries( hello blocksci/heuristics)
target_link_libraries(hello blocksci)
install(TARGETS hello DESTINATION bin)
```

Comment: getTaintedImpl isn't a function in the header: https://github.com/citp/BlockSci/blob/master/include/blocksci/heuristics/taint.hpp you can only use functions declared in a libraries headers

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you have any idea of which function should I use in order to get poison tainted outputs? @AlanBirtles

Comment: No idea I'm afraid, you could look in the documentation? I've not used blocksci before